# Truffle migrate fails

Tags: truffle, testrpc, truffle-migration

I am using testrpc. While running truffle migrate I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/truffle-contract/contract.js:671
        throw new Error(this.contract_name + " has no network configuration for its current network id (" + network_id + ").");
        ^

Error: XXXTokenFactory has no network configuration for its current network id (1497979617513).
```

My truffle.js as the following content

```
// Allows us to use ES6 in our migrations and tests.
require('babel-register')

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 8545,
      network_id: '*' // Match any network id
    }
  }
}
```

What am I missing? Would appreciate any help I get. Thanks

Comment: did you define your contract in migrations/2_deploy_contracts.js file?

Comment: Yes I did. Forgot to mention my XXXTokenFactory is an implementation of Open Zeppelin's MultisigWallet

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This seems to occur if you're trying to deploy contract `A` that depends on contract `B` before contract `B` has actually finished deploying.

You probably have something like this:

```
module.exports = function(deployer, network, accounts) {
  deployer.deploy(B);
  deployer.deploy(A, B.address);
};
```

It's essentially a race condition because `B.address` is probably not ready in time for the second `deployer.deploy` call.  So use the promise that `deploy` returns like this:

```
module.exports = function(deployer, network, accounts) {
  deployer.deploy(B).then(function() {
    return deployer.deploy(A, B.address);
  });
};
```

Comment: This solution didn't work for me. keep getting the same error.

Comment: Same for me until I noticed the `return` statement. After adding that, it worked.

Answer (score 7):

I prefer this syntax:

```
module.exports = function(deployer, network, accounts) {

    deployer.then(async () => {
        await deployer.deploy(A);
        await deployer.deploy(B, A.address);
        //...
    });
};
```

since it's way more readable when you have lots of contracts.

See also: https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/501#issuecomment-373886205