# Truffle Error: ContractName has no network configuration for its current network id (1575203139857)

Tags: solidity, truffle-migration, truffle-contract, truffle-deployment

Im doing the tutorial at https://github.com/ConsenSys-Academy/proof-of-existence-exercise and running into the following error:

```
$ truffle console
truffle(development)> var poe = await ProofOfExistence2.at(ProofOfExistence2.address)
Thrown:
Error: ProofOfExistence2 has no network configuration for its current network id (1575203139857).
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:1:48
    at Function.getter (C:\Users\mrleo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\contract\lib\contract\constructorMethods.js:243:1)
    at Function.get (C:\Users\mrleo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\contract\lib\contract\properties.js:129:1)
    at Function.getter (C:\Users\mrleo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\contract\lib\contract\constructorMethods.js:246:1)
    at Function.network (C:\Users\mrleo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\contract\lib\contract\properties.js:108:1)
truffle(development)> truffle(development)>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Truffle migrate fails](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/18432/truffle-migrate-fails)

Answer (score 1):

In the migrations directory you have to reference the deployments for any new contracts.

In this case that is the file 2_deploy_contracts.js:

```
var ProofOfExistence1 = artifacts.require('./ProofOfExistence1.sol');
var ProofOfExistence2 = artifacts.require('./ProofOfExistence2.sol');

module.exports = function(deployer) {
    deployer.deploy(ProofOfExistence1);
    deployer.deploy(ProofOfExistence2);
};
```

Then run:

```
truffle migrate --reset
```

This resolves the issue.

Therefore contract deployments have to be listed in a **migrations file**.

References:

[1] https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/running-migrations

[2] https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/truffle-commands

[3] https://medium.com/@blockchain101/demystifying-truffle-migrate-21afbcdf3264

Answer (score 1):

This error means that Truffle cannot find a network entry for the current network ID in the build artifact file.  Whenever a truffle migration is done, the build artifact JSON (typically under `build`) is updated to include a mapping of network ID to contract address.

Thus whenever you reset your test blockchain, e.g. restart `ganache-cli`, you need to re-deploy your contracts so that Truffle can find your contracts under the new network ID.

One way to avoid this issue is to specify a custom network ID, say `10312008`, when starting the test blockchain:

`ganache-cli -i 10312008 --db .ganache/data --deterministic`

The above also:

- specifies a data location for the blockchain state, as using the same network ID each time will probably not be very useful without your previously deployed contracts available on the blockchain
- specifies a fixed wallet mnemonic, in case your contract logic relies somehow upon deployer addresses, e.g. `msg.sender`; if that's not the case, you can remove this.  Note you can specify your own mnemonic using `--mnemonic` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when trying to access MyContract.address wthout trapping the block in a .then() so MyContract was not still deployed when truffle tryed to retrieve the address so it throwed an error.

```
deployer.deploy(MyContract)
     console.log(MyContract.address)
```

I forgot the ".then" block...

```
deployer.deploy(MyContract).then(()=>{
     console.log(MyContract.address)
})
```

And with that it worked perfectly.

I think your error may be somehow related to mine...